# Wait for AJAX to complete before returning from function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following

```
function doAjax()
{
  var result = false;
  $.ajax(url, data)
    .done(function(){
       // Do a bunch
       // of computation
       // blah blah blah
       result = true;
    }).fail(function(){
       result = false;
    });
  return result;
}

function doSomething()
{
  if ( doAjax() == true )
    console.log('success');
  else
    console.log('failed');
}

function doSomethingElse()
{
  if ( doAjax() == true )
    console.log('success');
  else
    console.log('failed');
}
```

I have a function that runs some ajax, then returns true or false, depending on whether the ajax was successful or not. This ajax function I call from multiple places in my code.

Because the function ends before the ajax finishes, it always returns false. How do I avoid this?

I have read something suggesting that I do a `return $.ajax()` in my function and then move the `.done()` and `.fail()` functions to my `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` functions. However, in my `.done()` method, I do a BUNCH of computation. Lots of code. So the problem is, that if I move the `.done()` function to my other functions, I am duplicating a bunch of code.

How do I avoid this? Just wrap the computation into it's own function and call it wherever necessary?

Comment: `result` will always `return false`, and it's normal, because ajax request is asynchronous. So you really has to use `.done()` or callback function. And yes: to avoid code duplicating (if you somehow got this problem) set necessary code to separate function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Restructure your code to use callbacks instead of returns, like this...

```
function doAjax(callback)
{
  $.ajax(url, data)
    .done(function(){
       // Do a bunch
       // of computation
       // blah blah blah
       callback(true);
    }).fail(function(){
       callback(false);
    });
}

function doSomething()
{
  doAjax(function(result){
    if (result == true )
       console.log('success');
    else
       console.log('failed');
  });
}

function doSomethingElse()
{
  doAjax(function(result){
    if (result == true )
       console.log('success');
    else
       console.log('failed');
  });
}
```

Comment: how to handle if the url is dynamic?

Comment: @reggie - Sounds like you have a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Answer (score 3):

Techincally you can make you ajax `synchronous` like this:

```
 $.ajax({url:myUrl, data:myData, async: false})
```

But this isn't recomended(only for really really specific things).
Otherwise, simply use `callbacks` as you can see in this example:

```
var menuId = $( "ul.nav" ).first().attr( "id" );    
var request = $.ajax({   
  url: "script.php",    
  type: "POST",    
  data: { id : menuId },   
  dataType: "html"    
});

request.done(function( msg ) {    
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );   
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {    
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );    
});
```

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER do `return` together with Ajax**, it will never work. Use Ajax `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost',
   success: function(data){
        var doStuff = true;
        var responseFromServer = data;
        callSomeFooFunction();
        //return will not work!
   }
})
```

Comment: I know this doesn't solve my problem, but according to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax, `.done()` replaces the deprecated `.success()` function.

Comment: @Jakobud Anyway, your function `return` (not in ajax) will be executed before ajax is done and `return` in ajax will return to nowhere, use callback functions

Answer (score 1):

It will not work, while your Ajax is in asynchronous mode (`async: false`). Try to structurize your code this way:

```
function doABuncnchOfComputation(args){ // no duplicates here
    // Do a bunch
    // of computation
    // blah blah blah
}

// doSomething:
$.ajax(url, data)
    .done(function(){
       doABuncnchOfComputation(...); // call with proper arguments, possibly received from server
       console.log('doSomething succeeded');
    }).fail(function(){
       console.log('doSomething failed');
    });

// doSomethingElse:
$.ajax(url, data)
    .done(function(){
       doABuncnchOfComputation(...); // call with proper arguments, possibly received from server
       console.log('doSomethingElse succeeded');
    }).fail(function(){
       console.log('doSomethingElse failed');
    });
```

So your main computation block `doABuncnchOfComputation()` will remain intact and accesible for each async operation.

Setting Ajax mode to synchronous will hold browser from any execution, while network transmission is in active state. Due to possible network instability, it may lead to "bad" user experience - browser may hang, page will be inactive and unresponsive, while Ajax will send/receive or be waiting for data. It is highly unreliable and discouraging.