# skipping the first get - jquery

Tags: jquery

on click playButton I perform 2 "get" in order to show an image in #playAreaImageand and an audio element and playlist in #playAreaSongs.
Usually this is displayed correctly but sometimes the program skips the first get and does the second and then the first one.
What is the reason for this behavior?

This is my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.playButton', function () {
    var playlistID = this.id;
    var playlistImage;
    var playlistUrl = 'http://localhost/playlist/api/playlist.php?type=playlist&id=';
    playlistUrl += playlistID;
    $('#playAreaImage').text('');
    $.getJSON(playlistUrl, function (result) {
        console.log('first');
        var playlistData = result.data;
        playlistImage = playlistData.image;
        playlistImage = `<img id="playlistImg" src="${playlistImage}">`;
    });
    $('#playAreaSongs').text('');
    url = "http://localhost/playlist/api/playlist.php?type=songs&id=";
    url += playlistID;
    let list = '<audio src=" " id="audioPlayer" controls onplay="playPlaylist();" onpause="pausePlaylist();">Sorry, your browser does not support audio!</audio>';
    list += "<ul id='playlist'>";
    $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, rowElement) {
            if (i === "data") {
                var songs = this.songs;
                $.each(songs, function (songI, song) {
                    if (songI === 0) {
                        list += `<li class='current-song'><a href="${this.url}" name="${this.name}">${this.name}</a></li>`;
                    } else {
                        list += `<li><a href="${this.url}" name="${this.name}">${this.name}</a></li>`;
                    }
                });
                list += `</ul>`;
                $('#playAreaSongs').append(list);
                $("#playAreaImage").append(playlistImage);
                $('#playArea').show().css('display', 'flex').attr('name', playlistID);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want to run the second get after the first, you need to put it in the callback function of the first - otherwise they will run asynchronously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for AJAX to complete before returning from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520261/wait-for-ajax-to-complete-before-returning-from-function)

Comment: call your second code after first getJSON success

Comment: Thank you all. I put the second get in the callback function of the first and it works! I believe I will remember this important information next time.